# Linker error: undefined reference to `_fini'

Tags: linker

I am just getting strted with lpcXpresso for embedded system development. It uses a modifed Eclise as its IDE and an MCU C compiler and MCU linker.

I imported some eisting code and had a few  linker errors, which I soon sorted out. But the final one has me stumped:

```
undefined reference to `_fini'
```

I would expect that that means that some of my code calls a function called `fini()` - right?

Except that I don't have one (admiteddly there is an `InitialzeTracingSubsystem()`). And I don't believe that the linker is truncating the name because it earlier complained of `_getimeofday`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show your command line. I am guessing you've used `ld` (the linker) directly.

Don't do that. Instead, *always* use the compiler driver to do the linking.

The `_init` and `_fini` are usually part of `libc`, or the C runtime startup files (`crt0.o`, `crtend.o`, etc.) that come with it.

The compiler driver will do the magic necessary to link them in. The linker would not.

Comment: +1 Sorry for taking a day to get back to you.  I am sure that taht is the problem but what confuses me is that it only appears when I -D define one of my own #defines to turn on debug tracing, where I write a trace log to a text file.  Any idea how to find the problem?

Comment: FWIW, I suspect my problem is calling printf() in code intended for an embedded system

Comment: I encountered this same issuing when porting some code to an embedded environment.  Turns out the code was calling exit() which ended up leading to _fini