# energia compilation error error _fini

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, code-composer

I am using Energia with cc3200 TI Evaluation Board and I have added a wavelet library from [this link](http://wavelet2d.sourceforge.net/) but after editing the library source file and compiling it gives this error:

```
/compressed/energia-0101e0017-windows/energia-0101e0017/hardware/tools/lm4f/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7e-m\libc.a(lib_a-fini.o): In function `__libc_fini_array':fini.c:(.text.__libc_fini_array+0x22): undefined reference to '_fini' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I did some google search and could not find any solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like a linker error. Seems like a library and object providing the "promised" symbol is not given to the "make" process or missing for the system. Maybe show what the compilation and link commands are (and look up prominent components on your system if they are where "expected" from those?

Comment: Take a look [at this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410383/linker-error-undefined-reference-to-fini)

Comment: The compilation and linking are done using the Energia only as it is an Arduino like IDE only I am unable to find the compilation and linking commands but I tried the same code in the raspberry pi with command "g++  filename.o libraryname.o -o outputname" and it worked without error.

Comment: Solved.! thanks a lot. Turns out the problem was the function was calling exit() as in the SO post.